# How can I set variable x as default when I upload a .CSV file on my App?

Tags: r, shiny

My Shiny Application's purpose is to upload a .csv file and plot a ggplot graph with its data.
When I upload a .csv file on my Shiny Application, the default variable is "y" for both input variables. However, when I change "y" to "x" on the "X Variable" input, the App works fine.
I just have to set "x" for "X Variable" input and "y" for "Y Variable" input as default when I upload the .csv file.

Here follows the app.R code with my comments and Error Message I get when I upload the file.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),

                 tags$br(),
                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),

                 selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "", selected = NULL),
                 selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = NULL)

               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents'),
                 plotOutput('MyPlot')
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1)

    inFile <- input$file1 

    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep)

    ## Update inputs
    ## I've already tried to change the selected = names(df) to selected = NULL on this part of the server code, but it didn't work.

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])

    return(df)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({

    xy <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    ggplot(data = xy, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()

  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error message I get is:

> "Error: object 'x' not found".

Comment: Welcome to SO! My guess is that it's the `ggplot()` call, I bet there are not actually columns in `xy` with the names `x` and `y`. Maybe you could use `aes(as.name(input$xcol), as.name(input$ycol))` instead? Hard to say for sure without a full [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)...

Comment: Thank you! I've tried using `aes(as.name(input$xcol), as.name(input$ycol))` and it didn't work. I've also tried changing the call `xy` and also failed :(

Comment: In aes() you have to match the names of the aesthetics with the names of the columns, try `aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to SO

Your issue here is that you update the `selectInput()` at the wrong time: the update is done once the server has finished computing, so here once the `data()` is done running.

So to be clear, you update your input **after** trying to select from it.

Other thing is that you need to `sym()` & `!!` the `input$` to make it work with `ggplot()` (see : https://github.com/ColinFay/tidytuesday201942/blob/master/R/mod_dataviz.R#L184 for example)

Here is a working version:

```r
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),

                 tags$br(),
                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),

                 selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "", selected = NULL),
                 selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = NULL)

               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents'),
                 plotOutput('MyPlot')
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  r <- reactiveValues(
    df = NULL
  )

  observe({
    req(input$file1$datapath)
    # req(input$xcol)
    # req(input$ycol)
    r$df <- read.csv(
      input$file1$datapath, 
      header = input$header, 
      sep = input$sep
    )
  })


  observeEvent( r$df   , {
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      inputId = 'xcol', 
      label = 'X Variable',
      choices = names(r$df), 
      selected = names(r$df)[1]
    )
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      inputId = 'ycol', 
      label = 'Y Variable',
      choices = names(r$df),
      selected = names(r$df)[2]
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)


  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(r$df)
    head(r$df)
  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(r$df)
    req(input$xcol)
    req(input$ycol)
    ggplot(
      data = r$df, 
      aes(!!sym(input$xcol), !!sym(input$ycol))
    ) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()

  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]